# Add 1 to variable if opacity is == 1 within a setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, var

I have a variable that I need to add 1 to each time an elements `opacity` is `1`. I need to keep checking the opacity so I have wrapped it in a `setInterval`.

I am wondering if there is a way to only add 1 to the variable each time the opacity changes to 1 instead of keep adding 1 over and over again because of the interval. Here is my code

```js
var number = 1;

var intervalsizer = setInterval(function() {
  if ($(".cardButtons__discuss").css('opacity') == 1) {
    number++;
    console.log(number)
  }

  function fooo() {
    if (number == 1) {
      //do something
    }
    if (number == 2) {
    }
    if (number == 3) {
      //do something
    }
    if (number == 4) {
      //do something
    }
  }
}, 50);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are going wrong way doing like that. Where are your logic behind opactity change?

Comment: I agre with @ManUtopiK, if you show us the logic and why you are proceeding in this way we might be able to suggest a better flow.

Comment: Just a hint: `if (n==1) {++n;} if (n==2) {++n;} if (n==3) {++n;}` Guess what's n afterwards if it was 1 initially. You most likely want to use `else if`.

Comment: I think he wants an alternate to setInterval to check opacity, e.g some sort of callback that can be triggered if opacity changes. Am I correct?

Comment: @Tapas You are correct I need to keep checking the opacity if there is a better option

Comment: How is opacity changing? Are you changing it using jquery? Whats causing it to change? The solution depends on this

Comment: JQuery is adding a class "isCard" which changes opacity via css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking an attribute can be done using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). This code tracks all attribute changes on the element and filters out changes to the `style` and `class` attributes specifically. When the attributes change it looks if the opacity value has changed.

This solution only works if the opacity is changed on the element itself, by setting a class or by setting a style.

```js
const mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv')

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if(mutation.attributeName !== 'style' && mutation.attributeName !== 'class') return;
    const target = $(mutation.target);
    const oldVal = target.data("oldOpacity");
    const newVal = getComputedStyle(target[0]).opacity;
    if(oldVal != newVal) {
      console.log(`opacity changed. Old: ${oldVal}, New: ${newVal}`)
      target.data("oldOpacity", newVal)
    }
  });    
});

const config = { 
  attributes: true 
};
 
observer.observe(mydiv, config);


//code to change the opacity and another style attribute.
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  switch (i % 4) {
    case 0:
      mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "red"
      break
    case 1:
      mydiv.style.opacity = "0.5"
      break
    case 2:
      mydiv.classList.add('blue')
      break
    case 3:
      mydiv.style.opacity = ""
      mydiv.classList.remove('blue')
      mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
      break;
  }
  i++;
}, 1000)
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#mydiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```